# Python pack data to PHP pack data

Tags: php, python, struct, pack

could someone help me get this data into the PHP equivalent: `>4siiiiiiiiiiiii8x` It is used in `struct.pack()` in Python.
this is what i got so far: `N14si13x8`
it's supposed to be returning: `('P3TF', 272, 64, 6832, 6896, 1426, 8336, 312, 8656, 0, 8656, 0, 8656, 2924384)`

The PHP version results:

```
array
  'si13x81' => int 1345541190
  'si13x82' => int 272
  'si13x83' => int 64
  'si13x84' => int 6832
  'si13x85' => int 6896
  'si13x86' => int 1426
  'si13x87' => int 8336
  'si13x88' => int 312
  'si13x89' => int 8656
  'si13x810' => int 0
  'si13x811' => int 8656
  'si13x812' => int 0
  'si13x813' => int 8656
  'si13x814' => int 2924384
```

still need to get the first one right.

Comment: Can you provide the input data (as base64)? This reads more like you want to `unpack()`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am trying to unpack. The source file is a PS3 theme file .p3t e.g.: http://download.ps3-themes.com/downloads3/11518-MyFirstTheme.p3t
The data shown is fread up to pointer 64 ( `fread($f, 64);` ) in binary reading mode ( `fopen('file.p3t', 'rb')` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main problem is that `i` and `s` have different meaning in PHP. To recreate your original list in PHP this seems to work:

```
print_r(unpack("a4header/N13int/x8fill", $p));
```

Gives me:

```
Array(
    [header] => P3TF
    [int1] => 272
    [int2] => 64
    [int3] => 6832
    [int4] => 6896
    [int5] => 1426
    [int6] => 8336
    [int7] => 312
    [int8] => 8656
    [int9] => 0
    [int10] => 8656
    [int11] => 0
    [int12] => 8656
    [int13] => 2924384
```

I'm not so sure about the `x8`. That's not used for padding in PHP. Maybe try `@` if it doesn't work on a real datafile.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Would you mind explaining it so i can understand it for future reference? Thanks

Comment: I only got it right by accident. The `s` in Python is `a` in PHP. And `N` is an explicitly big-endian 32-bit version of Pythons `i`. The PHP syntax uses a `/` delimiter and allows appending an array key name after each specifier or quantifier. That's because PHP returns an hash/array.